# Unit Testing InterruptedException for ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with Mockito Spy

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, interrupted-exception

I am using spring's `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` for executing tasks in multiple threads. The class looks like below

```
    @Component
    public class LoadData {
    //... ...    

        @Inject
        private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

        public SomeData getData(Long id) {
            Future<SomeData> loadData = taskExecutor.submit(() -> {
                    //return methodToGetDataSynchronously(id);
                    return new SomeData();
            });
            try {
                SomeData data = loadData.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                logger.error("error");
                //some more processing for the error here
            }
            return data;
       }
  }
```

To be able to unit test this class and cover the `InterruptedException` and `ExecutionException` branches, I have tried multiple approaches (using `Mockito` `Spy`), but have not been able to successfully test this.

Unit test class looks like below:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoadDataTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private LoadData loadData;

    @Spy
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor spyTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        spyTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(1);
        spyTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        spyTaskExecutor.initialize();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetData_shouldThrowInterruptedException () {
        Mockito.when(spyTaskExecutor.submit(Matchers.<Callable<SomeData>>any())).thenAnswer(new Answer<Future<SomeData>>() {
            public Future<SomeData> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                Future<SomeData> future = Mockito.mock(FutureTask.class);
                when(future.isDone()).thenReturn(false, false, true);
                when(future.get()).thenThrow(new InterruptedException ());
                return future;
            }
        });

        SomeData result = null;
        result = loadData.getData(101L);
        //verify here that InterruptedException processing was performed
    }
}
```

I am using `Spy` for `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` as I have other methods in the Test that tests the actual behavior of the multi threaded execution.
When I try to run the test method, it throws `NullPointerException` on stubbing spy:

```
Mockito.when(spyTaskExecutor.submit(Matchers.<Callable<SomeData>>any()))...
```

The exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:132)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.submit(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:320)
at com.company.LoadDataTest.testGetData_shouldThrowInterruptedException(LoadDataTest.java:20)
```

I think, the problem may be with the way I am stubbing the Mockito Spy. However, I am not sure if I am on the right path here to stub the `InterruptedException`. Has anyone got a sample of how to achieve this?

Versions:

```
  jdk-1.8.0_72
  junit-4.12
  mockito-core-1.10.19
  spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE
```

Note: this is an extract of the actual code. The actual code performs many other things and have many other beans injected into it - some of which are `Mock` in the `Test`, some are `Spy` - depending on what I am testing. I have only mentioned the part which I am facing an issue with here.

Comment: I jusr read across the JavaDoc from `MockitoJUnitRunner` and there it states `Initializes mocks annotated with Mock, so that explicit usage of MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(Object) is not necessary. Mocks are initialized before each test method.` so at least you can remove `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`. And you caould also try `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.StrictStubs.class)`

Comment: Oh and actually if you use `@InjectMocks` you have to instantiate your service under test i.e. `LoadData` in your `Before` -> `loadData = new LoadData();` right before `MocktitoAnnotations.init(this)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally figured out the issue. I was really close, just the use of Mockito Spy was a bit off. Here is the working solution:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoadDataTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private LoadData loadData;

    @Spy
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor spyTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        spyTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(1);
        spyTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        spyTaskExecutor.initialize();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetData_shouldThrowInterruptedException () {
        setupSpyTaskExecutorForException(new InterruptedException("junit"));

        SomeData result = loadData.getData(101L);
        //verify here that InterruptedException processing was performed
    }

    private void setupSpyTaskExecutorForException(Exception e) {
        Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Future<?>>() {
            public Future<?> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                Future<?> future = Mockito.mock(FutureTask.class);
                when(future.get()).thenThrow(e);
                return future;
            }
        }).when(spyTaskExecutor).submit(Matchers.<Callable<?>>any());
    }
}
```